# FoxPro ODBC/OLEDB in SSIS result inconsistencies

Tags: ssis, dbeaver, visual-foxpro

I am using SSIS to extract data from a .dbf-based ERP system. In SSIS, I have the Visual FoxPro OLEDB provider as a source and SQL Server OLEDB provider as a destination. The data copies quickly from the files into the sql table, but I have found that my results differ slightly depending on the Data Access Mode I use in the OLEDB source tool.

- When I opt for the "Table or view" setting and then select the table
  I want from the dropdown, I get 49,725 rows.
- When I opt for the "SQL command" setting and then use a SELECT * FROM
  [Table] query, I get 49,705 rows.
- The results are consistent between runs.

Looking in the folder that contains all the .dbf files, I find matching .cdx files for each table. Apparently .cdx files contain indexing and schema information for their accompanying .dbf? Is one of these access methods (select * vs. table dropdown) utilizing the .cdx while copying data, therefore producing more accurate results?

While validating with an ancient revision of DBeaver:

- I have found that the 49,705 rowcount dataset is missing some rows that are found if you use WHERE clause to locate them individually
- I have found that the 49,725 rowcount dataset produces some rows that look like duplicates save a few columns, and looking these rows up individually returns just one of the rows